# Set Twilio Client offline

Tags: javascript, twilio

How can I set a twilio js client to be offline, ie a client may want to temporarily not receive incoming calls?

Looking at the [twilio.js client library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js), I can see an offline event that is fired when a client goes offline. The documentation explains this occurs when the connection drops or the token expires but not how to do this manually.

I have thought about recalling the `Device.setup()` method with an invalid token to take the client offline, then reuse a valid one to reconnect when the client comes online. I'd be surprised if there wasnt a better option!

Answer (score 2):

Having used Twilio a little more I think I can answer my own question.

The Twilio js client is not designed to be taken offline or control/store a clients presence. Twilio does not maintain state.

Instead your Twilio application (the one that responds to the webhooks with TwiML) should store a list of connected/present agents (in-memory or db) which it can then use to choose which connected js client to direct an incoming call to. Therefore also having the ability to not direct calls to an agent that is not present or marked as away.